# How to capture the text from web elements having different attributes into a list using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNR1X.png)I am trying to capture the text from a Webpage where the attributes is different for every element.
==== Attribute===

**NX-2896HCP**

Attached is the Snapshot of the Webpage
For some elements the attributes is same while for some it is different

Help will be appreciated

Comment: ===Attribute-== <div qxselectable="on" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; touch-action: none; z-index: 10; box-sizing: border-box; position: absolute; user-select: text; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.4; left: 10px; top: 6px; width: 80px; height: 18px;">NX-2896HCP</div>

Comment: I don't see an attachment